# How to get data router outlet component to HeaderComponent?

Tags: angular

I have require some data in route-outlet component to HeaderComponent.

**Please check my below image.**

[image]

Comment: You should use `sharedService`. Service data will be shared among components.

Comment: @micronyks: I know to use sharedService. But, one problem. How to change my header title automatically?

Answer (score 4):

You can emit an event from the shared sevice and subscribe to this event in your header component like:

in your current route component:

```
onEvent() {
  this.sharedService.changeTitle(newTitle);
}
```

in service:

```
titleChanged = new EventEmitter();

changeTitle(title) {
  this.titleChanged.emit(title);
}
```

in header Component:

```
 title: string = '';
 ngOnInit(){
   this.sharedService.titleChanged.subscribe(title => this.title = title);
 }
```

Comment: your post is very useful. But, some wrong in your post.

Comment: What errors do you get ? "onEvent" is just a sample name, you can call this method from the place in your code where the title changes...

Comment: your post is absolutely my solution. please show my posted answer. and i have vote your answer :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

**1) admin.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class AdminService {
    titleChanged = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {}

    changeTitle(title) {
        this.titleChanged.emit(title);
    }
}
```

**2) app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { AdminService } from '../common/service/admin.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  //providers: [AdminService],
  template: `
   <left-menu></left-menu>
   <div class="main-panel">
      <app-header [header_title]="_header_title"></app-header>
      <div class="content">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
   </div>

  `
})
export class AdminComponent {

    public _header_title:string = "";
    constructor(route: ActivatedRoute,private _admin: AdminService) {
        this._admin.titleChanged.subscribe(title => this._header_title = title);
    }
}
```

**3) user-profile.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AdminService } from '../common/service/admin.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'user-profile',
  templateUrl : `./app/user-profile/user-profile.component.html` 
})
export class UserProfileComponent {
    private username:string="Bharat Chauhan";
    constructor(private _admin: AdminService) {
        this._admin.changeTitle("User Profile");
    }
}
```